# SQLAlchemy lazy sa.select([])

Tags: sqlalchemy, python-3.7

I use column properties to refer to properties of other tables.
I'd like to be able to select arbitrary information from other models indepentend of the declaration order of the models.
Just like `sa.orm.relationship` declares its relation by strings.

The problem I face is, that `property_of_a` can not be initialized, because `ModelB` is not declared at that moment.

Here is a simplified (not working) example.

A working alternative for this example might use [sa.ext.associationproxy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html)
I do not think, that I can use association proxies because I'd like to be able to use `CONCAT`, `GROUP_CONCAT` and `IF-THEN-ELSE` Queries.

Is there a way to initialize a sa.select query lazy (for example by strings like `sa.orm.relationship`)

```
import sqlalchemy as sa

Base = sa.ext.declarative.declarative_base()
metadata = Base.metadata

class ModelA(Base):
  __tablename__ = "model_a_table"

  id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
  name = sa.Column(sa.String(255), nullable=False, unique=True)

  model_b_id = sa.Column(sa.ForeignKey('model_b_table.id', ondelete='SET NULL'), index=True)
  model_b = sa.orm.relationship("ModelB")

  property_of_a = sa.orm.column_property(sa.select([ModelB.name]).where(ModelB.id == model_b_id))

class ModelB(Base):
  __tablename__ = "model_b_table"

  id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
  name = sa.Column(sa.String(255), nullable=False, unique=True)

  model_a_id = sa.Column(sa.ForeignKey('model_a_table.id', ondelete='SET NULL'), index=True)
  model_b = sa.orm.relationship("ModelA")

  property_of_b = sa.orm.column_property(sa.select([ModelA.name]).where(ModelB.id == model_a_id))

sa.orm.configure_mappers()
```

Comment: Hi, did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I haven't found a lazy solution, but you can achieve the same with `ModelA.property_of_a = sa.orm.column_property(sa.select([ModelB.name]).where(ModelB.id == model_b_id))` right before `sa.orm.configure_mappers()`